# Where specifically should I download Ruby and Ruby on Rails on Mac 10.6.4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

Where should I go to download it. What exactly do I need. What should I do to install it?

Comment: It is realllllly important on Mac OS 10.6 to know what you are doing when updating Ruby installed by Apple. Snow Leopard installs code that uses Ruby in `/usr/bin`. Changing that Ruby, or gems it supplied, could break the functionality but you wouldn't know it for days or weeks. You're better off using a RVM sandbox, or a Ruby installed into `/usr/local/` and leave the system Ruby alone. `find /usr -name '*.rb'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do: (on a Terminal)

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Then :

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: will this give me the latest version?

Comment: Yes, `rails 3.0.4` but with `Ruby 1.8.7`

Comment: and for the latest version of Ruby?

Comment: You should go for the @simone-carletti 's answer and [install RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). But, rails3 perform very well with ruby 1.8.7 :-)

Comment: WARNING:  Installing to ~/.gem since /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 and
   /usr/bin aren't both writable.
WARNING:  You don't have /Users/newcomputer/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin in your PATH,
   gem executables will not run.
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
 bundler requires RubyGems version >= 1.3.6
I get these errors when running "gem install rails"

Comment: Now: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions into the /usr/bin directory.

Comment: You need to be an admin or have admin privileges. Using `sudo` you can gain this privileges entering your password.

Answer (score 4):

Both Ruby and Ruby on Rails are already installed on Snow Leopard.
You can see the ruby version by running

```
$ ruby --version
```

However, Snow Leopard has a very old Rails version and a quite outdated Ruby version. I suggest you to [install RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/) and use it to install Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.

Comment: for some reason this command: bash < <(curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-head) does not work for me. Maybe I don't have the latest git version?

Comment: Maybe you don't have `curl` or `git`. You can install them via Homebrew http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/

Comment: Check out the Homebrew documentation from the link above.

Comment: You need to install Homebrew, before installing any library with brew. Please read the Homebrew documentation.

Comment: `brew install wget` is an example of how to install something *using* homebrew, not an instruction. (And it's a bad example actually because brew couldn't install wget the first time I tried it :D)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the directions that I use:

1) install the apple developer tools (ie Xcode).

You can find XCode on the "Mac OS Install DVD" that came with your laptop. If you don't have this disk, you can download it from apple developer tools. It is over 2 gigs, so go get a cup of coffee. Why do we install this The Ruby on Rails version shipped with OS X is a production version of Ruby and does not include the ruby headers. Because you will want to use a debugger, you will want to install apple developer tools.

2) install rvm

RVM allows you to have multiple versions of ruby on your system and the same time and quickly switch between them. We'll use it because it provides a nice abstraction layer.

- source for these directions: http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/
- on the command line, type "bash < <( curl http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/releases/rvm-install-latest )"
- Once it is finished, it will ask you to do several things.
- On my machine, I put the following line at the end of my .profile -- on a new machine you might not yet have a .profile file. In your terminal window, type vi .profile,

  - to insert code type "i"
  - to exit editing mode hit the escape key
  - to save and quit type ":wq"
  - "[[ -s $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
- Kill all open terminal windows
- Validate that you have rvm installed properly, start a new terminal window and type "type    rvm | head -n1" -- you should see "rvm is a function"

3) install ruby (feel free to pick a different version of ruby than this one)

from the command line type "rvm install ruby-1.8.7-p302"
   * From a terminal window type "rvm --default ruby-1.8.7-p302"
   * Type "rvm list", you should see "=> ruby-1.8.7-p302 [ x86_64 ]" 3)

4) update ruby gem manager

from the command line type "sudo gem update --system"

5) instal rails

"gem install rails -v 3.0.4 --no-rdoc --no-ri"

6) install mongrel

In a terminal window, type "gem install mongrel"

7) install bundler

from a terminal window, type "gem install bundler"

8) getting started

You may want to read Michael Hartl's online tutorial. http://ruby.railstutorial.org/